# didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not calling in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I just select/tap on item, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method was not called. But when I long press on item then `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` it is calling work perfectly. Why it happens like this. What should I did wrong?

I added collection view as follows

collectionview_followers.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, SCREEN_WIDTH, 150)

```
    collectionview_followers.delegate = self

    collectionview_followers.dataSource = self

    collectionview_followers.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FollowersCell")

    collectionview_followers.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    collectionview_followers.userInteractionEnabled = true

    collectionview_followers.allowsSelection = true

    view_collectionviewBG.addSubview(collectionview_followers)
```

and cell contains uiview with image and label

Comment: Have you used any gesture on this view controller ?

Comment: Show some code here!

Comment: You should add some code I agree with @SohilR.Memon. But you probably didn't set the `allowsSelection` to true (see my answer below).

Comment: @rani you are using any buttons on your Custome view?

Comment: make sure u use didSelectItemAtIndexPath method not didDeSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: you have added uiview in cell may be that is creating issue... try by removing it once and then again add uiview and make sure user interaction enable for uiview... because 2 days ago i also faced same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `self.tableView.allowsSelection = true` in the `viewDidLoad` method before the `super.ViewDidLoad()`.